# In a dataframe how can I count a specific value and then select the value with the highest count to create another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to select specific rows of data from a dataframe.  Here is an example of the dataframe.

```
Id  \  Value
0    002D85EF   5
1    002D85EF   1
2    002D85EF   5
3    00557D1B   1
4    00557D1B   1
5    00557D1B   5
6    0063EAFB   5
7    0063EAFB   5
8    0063EAFB   5
9    006DE4E3   1
10   006DE4E3   5
11   006DE4E3   1
12   006DE4E3   5
```

I am looking for an output frame like this:

```
Id  \  Value
0    002D85EF   5
1    00557D1B   1
2    0063EAFB   5
```

Note,  ID 006DE4E3  is not in the output because there the counts of the value was equal.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since i can not comment, i directly try to give You a hint, probably not the answer.)

try:

```py
df.groupby('Value').max()
```

or

```py
df.groupby('Value').count().max()
```

btw. the given row ids in Your answer do not match the above frame row ids and values. Also i don't understand why You do not select the `10   006DE4E3   5` row

**edit**
after clarification, i think You want is:
return the first of each occurrence of the Id (in a sorted frame). But only, if the all values of the ids group are not distributed equally.
For that my answer is:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.random.randint(5, high=10, size=(20, 1))
b = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 20)[:, None]
c = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([b,a]), columns=['id', 'value'])


def first_or_none(grp, col_name):
    cnts = grp.groupby(col_name).count()
    if len(cnts) == len(cnts.nunique()):
        return None
    else:
        return grp.iloc[0]

c.groupby(['id']).apply(first_or_none, 'value').dropna()
```

In this example the frame *c* is unsorted...

Comment: I excluded ID 006DE4E3 because there are an equal amount of  "1" and "5" values in the orginal dataframe.

Comment: Ok. Do You want then to select the first occurrence of each id, except if the number of values for each of the id have a matching number of value counts?

Comment: If the counts are matching, I want to skip that id .  Thank you for your help.